# what is best approch to handle data when host Activity is not active

Tags: android, view, background-process

I have four activity Activity1,Activity2,Activity3,Activity4. Activity2 has some operation where we need to communicate with server that means we will send some request and according to request response will come.

1. I click on button which will communicate with server in Activity2.
2. Now i moved to Activity3 and Activity4.
3. Still background process is happening for communication between server and client(android device).
4. When i am at Activity4 , then Activity2 background process get finish.
5. Now i come back from Activity4 to Activity3 and  Activity2.
6. Now i want, response should be appear form background process to Activity2.

What should be approach for this kind of use-case.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Activity2 On button click:

1) use `AsynchTask` to fetch data.

2) use startActivityForResult to start activity3.

3) and `onActivityResult` you can check your result

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), when you click the button, you launch a Intent to the Service to start the background task, at this point you app and the network task run asynchronously, you can move to the next Activities and make all you need, in the onResume method of your Activity 2 you can ask the status of the service with a Intent, if the task finished OK, you can retrieve the response of the service launching a Intent and cache it into Activity 2 on the onNewIntent method. In the service you gonna need a place to saves the response of the task, you can chooses how to do it (SQLite, SharedPreferences, Files, etc.) and only retrieve the response. You only need think in the logic of handle the request in the Service, store and retrieve the responses to the app.

Answer (score 0):

Well Its my guess, I can tell you how to handle it,

1) While in Activity 2 `use seperate thread apart from UIThread` for server operation , once started The parallel thread will take its own time and after server process over use any of `3 storage modes(sdcard,sqlite,sharedpref)` to store ur data ,,

2) You may know once your activity 3 starts , activity2 will be `paused(onPause)` , and then `stopped (onStop)` and will remain active in ur stack,

3)once u come back from activity 3 , use `onResume` to take back the saved data and use it ...